# Solving an equation involving the floor function

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find all  $x \in \mathbb R$ for which $$ \lfloor 2x\rfloor +\lfloor 3x\rfloor =1$$
> where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

What is the way to approach these type of question? I have tried to use the fact that $\lfloor x+k \rfloor =\lfloor x \rfloor +k$ to answer the question but I am not able to simplify. This is in my 12th grade math textbook.

EDIT: i tried to solve it graphically and the answer came out to be [$\frac{1}{3}$,$\frac{1}{2}$)

Comment: Please do not just repost [old questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4692792/2x3x-1-is-the-greatest-integer-function). Instead, rewrite the question adding your thoughts, and what results you can already use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[2x\]+\[3x\]=1 \[•\] is the greatest integer function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4692792/2x3x-1-is-the-greatest-integer-function)

Comment: I'll use $[ \cdot ]$ for the floor function. A few hints: Draw the graphs of $[2x]$ and $[3x]$. You've probably studied, at some point, transformations of graphs -- viz the relationship between $f(kx)$, for some constant $k$, and $f(x)$. That's exactly the type of transformation here. So if you know what $[x]$ looks like, you'll have a headstart. Once you have those two graphs, "add" them to get the graph of $g(x) = [2x] + [3x]$. Find where this graph intersects $y=1$. If you can answer your own question correctly and explain a general rule for how $g(x)$ behaves, I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: By the way, the rule you cited is valid only when $k$ is an integer.  So if you're trying to break up $2x$ into, say, $x + x$, it might not be valid here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  previously asked the same question but it got closed before anyone could answer it, so i reposted it.

Comment: @dmk i an aware that k should be an integer i was trying to apply the property for the 1 given in the right hand side. i tried the graghical approach and my answer was : x ∈ [1/3,1/2)

Comment: @dmk i was not able to draw the graph of g(x) as you said but i modified the equation as [2x]=1-[3x]. then using transformation of graphs i drewe the graphs of LHS and RHS and was able to find the interval [1/3,1/2), let me know if i am correct

Comment: If $x < 1/3$, then $2x < 2/3$, which means that $[2x] \le 0$; and $3x < 1$, which means $[3x] \le 0$ -- and so the sum of both floors is less than $1$. Moreover, if $x \ge 1/2$, both floor functions are at least $1$, and so their sum is at least $2$. Only when $x$ is in the range you gave is one of the floors $0$ and the other $1$. So, yes, you are correct.

Comment: You know that the sum of both terms is small -- namely, $1$ -- which means their magnitudes have to be similar. However, both terms come from -- how should I put it? -- similar places: One is something like two times some number and the other something like three times it. We can't have one floor evaluating to, say, $16$ and the other $-15$ because if $x<0$, both floors are negative, and if $x > 0$, both are non-negative. This really restricts where we can look for $x$-values that meet our requirement.

Comment: @dmk thanks a lot for your help, i was stuck on this for quite a while because i was trying to solve it theoretically.